# C# class for specific JSON / Geckoboard / Trendline widget

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, geckoboard

For Geckoboard I want to generate a JSON like this:

```
{
"item": [
    {
      "value": "274057"
    },
    [
      "38594",
      "39957",
      "35316",
      "35913",
      "36668",
      "45660",
      "41949"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I am struggling with the missing property before the array.

How must the C# Class look like to serialize to that?

Comment: Look at your JSON as XML: http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.VR6QAvnF_hk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those works fine for dynamic languages, like javaScript, but it is not so easy to do same thing in C#. The best i can see here - this whole JSON will map to following class structure:

```
public class RootItem
{
    public IEnumerable<object> Item {get;set;}
}

public class ValueItem 
{
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

And basically next you will need a custom serializer rules or parameter binder (depending where you are using it), that will take this JSON and manually fill `RootItem.Item` collection with either collection of `ValueItem` or `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

Paste your json to [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), and generate a suitable class definition for serializing that json there :

```cs
public class RootObject
{
    public List<object> item { get; set; }
}
```

Json `item` property defined as an array containing mixed data type (singular object and array), and one possible data type to hold both type in .NET is `object`.